# How to compare CGFloat in XCTestCase?

Tags: xctest

I can't understand this at all. What is the problem here?

I've tried typing `1.0`, `1.0f`, `(CGFloat) 1.0` and `(CGFloat)(2.0 - 1.0)`. Every time the same error.

[image: Screenshot from xcode]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would recommend using `FLT_EPSILON` for this:

`XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(mov.lastDelta, 0.0f, FLT_EPSILON, @"");`

Unless you have some reason to require a larger epsilon.

Answer (score 6):

The fractional part of your numbers, 0.9, cannot be represented accurately by a float.
Some rounding will happen, and that's probably the reason for the fail.

0.9 = (1/2) + (1/4) + (1/8) + (1/64) + (1/128) + (1/1024) + (1/2048) + (1/16384) + (1/32768) + (1/262144) etc etc = 0,8999978005 etc.

Fractions that look round to the human eye may not be round in the binary system.

0.5 is a round number for the cpu = (1/2).

0.75 is round for the cpu = (1/2) + (1/4).

Even 0,9072265625 is round   ( (1/2) + (1/4) + (1/8) + (1/32) + (1/1024) )

But not 0.9 or 0.1. Not even 0.2 :)

EDIT: And, of course, use an epsilon for comparing floats.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to

```
mov.value = 8.9
XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(mov.lastDelta, 0.0f, 0.001, @"");
```

and it seems to work just fine now...